# How can I get the right image src when I do an onclick function using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a game that when the start button is clicked, it dynamically deletes that div element and creates a new one in order to show the images I want the user to see. **MY GOAL IS THAT WHEN THE USER CLICKS ON THE IMAGE** it will console log the src of the image it clicked to verify which image was clicked. My code works. My problem is that when I click any of the images, it can't tell the difference between the images sources.

would it be good to put an onclick function inside the if statement? I was thinking...if this source is clicked, then console log it's source.

```
//startButton onclick function//

$("#startButton").on("click", function (event) {

//when button is clicked, it removes intro-container div and everything inside//

    $(this).closest(".intro-container").remove();

//image sources//

    kevImage = 'src=assets/images/kevin-durant.png';
    lebImage = 'src=assets/images/kobe-bryant.png';
    kobImage = 'src=assets/images/lebron-james.png';
    micImage = 'src=assets/images/michael-jordan.png';

//dynamically creating new elements//

    $("#characterPage").append("<div class= intro-container>" +
        "<h1> CHOOSE YOUR BALLER" + "</h1>" +
        "<div class=image-container>" +
        "<img class = image " + kevImage + ">" + "<img class = image " + lebImage + ">" +
        "<img class = image " + kobImage + ">" + "<img class = image " + micImage + ">" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>");

//onclick on image class

    $(".image").on("click", function (event) {

//if statement that executes only if kevImage is selected

        if (kevImage) {
            console.log('correct');
        } else {
            console.log('wrong');
        }

    });


});
```

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10xTf.png)

Comment: `$(this).attr('src')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$(".image").attr('src')`
and log the result in the console.

Comment: not sure what you mean..should I put that inside the if statement?

Comment: Wherever you need to use it. This statement will give you the source of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with this:

```
$(".image").on("click", function (event) {

                if ($(".image").attr('src')) {
                    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
                } else {
                    console.log('wrong');
                }

            });
```